# Как организовать хранение списка портов?

Tags: g++, сокет, c++, linux

Есть задача:

Есть список портов, скажем 2000 портов, и нужно для каждого подключившегося клиента открывать отдельный порт в новом потоке и после выполнения закрывать. Как открывать и закрывать я понимаю, но как выделять эти порты не имею представления.

Под выделением порта имеется в виду, что человек подключился, ему выделили порт и он переключился на этот порт.

Как организовать хранение списка портов и их выделение чтоб избежать ситуаций когда один и тот же порт будет выделен многим людям?  Приложение многопоточное.

Параллельно подключилось много людей и каждому нужен порт.

Comment: Что значит "выделять порты для каждого подключившегося"? Что с этими портами надо будет делать (для справки почитайте, как устанавливается tcp-соединение).

Или это будет какое-то общение по udp? Т.е. смысл вопроса сильно непонятен.

Comment: Я пишу сервер и необходимо чтобы каждый клиент обрабатывался в отдельном порте.
То есть есть один порт к которому подключается клиент, получает номер порта для дальнейшей работы и переподключается, но уже к тому порту который получил. После того как мы отправили клиенту номер порта мы начинаем слушать этот порт в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Обмен будет идти по какому протоколу?

Comment: tcp/ip. На базе сокетов.

Comment: Т.е. tcp. Порты слушает сервер, соединения устанавливают клиенты. Допустим, сервер слушает порты 2000-3999. Клиент устанавливает соединение с портом 2000 и создаётся канал порт клиента (какой-то) <-> порт сервера (какой-то). 2000 -- только слушать и устанавливать соединение. В создании канала участвует совсем другой порт. Вопрос, нафига слушать 2000 портов?

Если бы у вас обмен шёл по udp, то да. Там каждый клиент посылал бы дейтаграммы на определённый порт, который сервер должен бы был слушать. В случае tcp так не делают.

Comment: Мне дали такую задачу,Поэтому и думаю как бы сделать так.

Comment: А дословно условие задачи можете привести? Потому что это очень похоже на какой-то tcp-сервер, который слушает один конкретный порт, а обмен с клиентами, как и полагается, осуществляет по другим (правда номер порта он не передаёт, тот и так доступен клиенту после установления соединения). Примеров таких выше крыши, организация сервера -- самая разная (отдельные процессы, отдельные потоки, один поток -- event driven, посредством select или poll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно юзать мютексы или критические секции. Я уже не помню деталей, но, вроде бы, критические секции сделаны как раз для таких случаев. Я делаю так на срр в заголовке:

---

```
#ifndef _AUTO_CRITICAL_SECTION_H_
#define _AUTO_CRITICAL_SECTION_H_

#include "CriticalSection.h"

class AutoCriticalSection
{
public:
    AutoCriticalSection(CriticalSection& section);
    ~AutoCriticalSection();

private:
    AutoCriticalSection(const AutoCriticalSection& section);
    AutoCriticalSection& operator=(const AutoCriticalSection& section);

    CriticalSection& section_;
};

#endif // _AUTO_CRITICAL_SECTION_H_
```

Реализация:

---

```
#include "AutoCriticalSection.h"

AutoCriticalSection::AutoCriticalSection(CriticalSection& section)
    : section_(section)
{
   section_.Enter();
}
AutoCriticalSection::~AutoCriticalSection()
{
   section_.Leave();
}
```

Использование (в процедуре просто пишем):

---

```
CriticalSection sec;
AutoCriticalSection section(sec);
```

Где хидер:

---

```
#ifndef _CRITICAL_SECTION_H_
#define _CRITICAL_SECTION_H_

#include <setupapi.h>

class CriticalSection
{
public:
    CriticalSection();
    virtual ~CriticalSection() ;

    void Enter();
    void Leave();

private:
    CriticalSection(const CriticalSection&);
    CriticalSection& operator=(const CriticalSection&);

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection_;
};

#endif // _CRITICAL_SECTION_H_
```

Реализация этого:

---

```
#include "CriticalSection.h"

CriticalSection::CriticalSection()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&criticalSection_);
}
CriticalSection::~CriticalSection()
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&criticalSection_);
}
void CriticalSection::Enter()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection_);
}
void CriticalSection::Leave()
{
    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection_);
}
```

Comment: @Airhand: зачем такой велосипед? Есть же [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: Просто я за std::lock_guard ничего не знаю.